# List of Tables not showing chapter name in table of contents

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, tocloft

[Overleaf link for the project](https://www.overleaf.com/3419479661hkyszkncjrkp)  I am using \listoftables to generate list of table in Table of Contents, the table number in the content is showing along with Chapter number (e.g. Table 1.1 Table title), but in the Table of contents it is showing as (1 Table title).

Comment: No idea what you are doing. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass..` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. You mention Chapters but there are at least 4 classes that provide for chapters. Are you using one of those or something completely different? --- GOM

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PeterWilson I've added overleaf link to the project, using table i'm getting the chapter number in 'list of tables' but using longtblr I'm not getting that . Please help

Comment: An Overleaf link does not count as a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497).  Also, reconsider your choice of tags, as this doesn't actually have anything to do with Overleaf.

Comment: I asked for an MWE but you decided not to provide one so nobody can help you. You have to do some work providing code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To add the word Table in the List of Tables (and the word Figure in the List of Figures) add this code before `\begin{document)`

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\tablename\space}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{5ex}  
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\space}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{6ex}
```

[image: a]

(Also remove     `\usepackage{floatrow}` and    `\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}` from your preamble if you do not use it, load `hyperref` as the last package}